# How do I enable small movements of the trackpad in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, touchpad

When I move the mouse with the trackpad and I want to select text or click a small button, I move the mouse in the general vicinity but slow down and stop then try to move it more precise. However, when I stop, the touchpad stops responding! I have to pick up my finger, put it back down, then start moving again. It's really annoying when trying to precisely place the pointer. In other instances, I place my finger down and try to roll my finger, but the mouse doesn't move. In other instances, I move my finger slowly, the mouse moves a millimeter, but then stop responding, even though I didn't stop moving and I didn't life my finger up. It seems it will only recognize sudden, fast movements.

I have it set to the highest sensitivity already. How do I increase the sensitivity or keep it from not responding when I move it slowly or in small increments?

[image: most sensitive]

Samsung #NP940X5N, Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: For now I changed the cursor speed from 7 to 4. I'll see how/if that helps.