# Synaptics Trackpad Hysteresis/Backlash/Noise Rejection

Tags: drivers, windows-registry, touchpad, thinkpad, synaptics-touchpad

I am using a Lenovo ThinkPad T480 with a Synaptics trackpad, running Windows 10. The issue that I am facing is with a feature that appears to come with the Synaptics drivers (since it goes away when I remove the driver) which prevents small movements from being registered on the cursor, when starting from rest or reversing the cursor direction.

This is similar to mechanical "backlash" that is usually observed when interfacing multiple gears, where there is a small "dead zone" when direction is reversed. Basically, when starting off from a stationary position on the trackpad, I have to first move my finger about 1mm before the cursor starts moving. If I reverse direction, my finger needs to move 2mm before the cursor starts moving in the opposite direction.

Although this is likely a feature that prevents movement of the cursor when tap-clicking, it greatly reduces the precision that I require to work productively.

Under Linux, I have observed people referring to this as a "noise cancellation" feature,

> *The synaptics has a built-in noise cancellation based on hysteresis. This means that incoming coordinates actually shift a box of predefined dimensions such that it covers the incoming coordinate, and only the boxes own center is used as input. Obviously, the smaller the box the better, but the likelyhood of noise motion coming through also increases.*

where the parameters, `HorizHysteresis` and `VertHysteresis` can be used to adjust this box size.

I have been digging through the Windows 10 registry directories, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTP` and `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTP`, looking for similar values, but to no avail.

- Where is the registry value for this that I can use to reduce the level of noise rejection on the trackpad, in Windows 10?
- Would it be possible to add one? If not, what could be an alternative solution?
- Is there a different driver that I could possibly use?

[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1395583/how-do-i-enable-small-movements-of-the-trackpad-in-windows) is a similar post that unfortunately never got a solution.

Comment: I find a Track Pad to be counterproductive, and always use and carry a Bluetooth Mouse.

Comment: The raw input HID_USAGE_DIGITIZER_TOUCH_PAD data has almost no hysteresis - it's 90% as good as Linux xf86-input-synaptics with all that faff disabled. I can look at releasing the program I have to translate that to mouse movements if there is interest... atm a lot of caveats such as no palm rejection, no acceleration (good), no sensitivity adjustment, probably bannable in anti-cheat

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the values here:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PrecisionTouchPad\`

I found this article for tuning TouchPads:
[Precision touchpad tuning](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/component-guidelines/touchpad-tuning-guidelines)

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like that article and registry directory does not contain the required setting I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Input\Settings\ControllerProcessor\CursorSpeed Or
ctrl+F and type AAPThreshold and when changing the variable of that setting it goes as follows
Sensitive: 0
High Sensitivity: 1
Medium Sensitivity: 2
Low sensitivity: 3

Comment: AAPThreshold sets the amount of cool-down time that tap-clicking is deactivated after the keyboard has been used. I'm afraid that is not what I am looking for.